Is it possible to justify differing confidences in our beliefs?
We all feel more confident in certain things more than others. For example, we may feel more confident that “the sun will rise tomorrow” than “I will die tomorrow.”
But how does one (or does it even make sense to) justify this? I can perhaps see an inductive justification for this but induction as Hume pointed out cannot be justified conclusively or even probabilistically.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCnchhausen_trilemma

"or does it even make sense to?" -Maybe you should ensure that your question makes sense before asking it .

I don't know how to reduce this to logic, but intuitively I know that there are risks that could kill me any day (e.g. a car accident), but I don't know of any mechanism that's likely to prevent the sun from rising.

@tkruse that’s the whole point of asking the question, “does it even make sense to” does not mean in a semantic sense, but more of a philosophical sense. What a ridiculous comment.

@Barmar yes, so you are intuitively able to point out reasons why one belief may be more rational than another, but how do you objectively show this? How would you respond to someone who says your intuitions are invalid or that the reasons for your justification are invalid?

This article might be the answer, though the phrasing of the question is too unclear to even tell. https://eujournalfuturesresearch.springeropen.com/articles/10.1007/s40309-015-0076-7

Perhaps all you need for your justification at this level is nothing but pan psyches to fix the horizon landscape of the there with intersubjectivity aka objectivity...

This question is similar to: What would constitute as justification?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Also in this shape the question seems apply answereds by various other questions tagged with "justification".

@tkruse that is asking about justification in general. This question is specifically about differing confidence levels among beliefs. Do you ctrl + F the same keywords in different questions and then automatically consider them duplicate?

As Karl Popper pointed out, induction is impossible, see this reading list:
https://fallibleideas.com/books#popper
A theory is either true or false and no finite number of observations implies the truth of a theory or raises its probability.
What happens instead is that knowledge is created by guesswork controlled by criticism. You notice problems with existing ideas, propose solutions to those problems and criticise them until only one solution is left. No justification is required.
The whole idea of justification is a mistake. You should be interested in trying to find ways to improve your ideas not entrench your existing ideas. In practice any idea has aspects that aren't well understood or can't be applied to a relevant problem easily. These are problems that should be addressed by replacing the idea with a variant that solves the problem. Sometimes that variant is small, like coming up with a model that treats both measurement devices and measured systems using quantum theory or sometimes it is large like replacing classical electromagnetic models of the atom with quantum models. Assigning scores of how much justification an idea has and adding them up is vulnerable to abuse since it distracts you into arguing about scores instead of solving problems. For more explanation see
https://criticalfallibilism.com/introduction-to-critical-fallibilism/

How would you address an example like the sun rising every day then? Suppose you have no explanation for why or how the sun rises. But presumably, you would be more justified in thinking that it will rise tomorrow if you’ve observed it rise 1000 times than if you observed it rise 10 times. Why do you think this pattern of reasoning has no basis? I do admit that the reasoning would perhaps be circular as Hume pointed out, sure, but it also seems to go at odds with the obvious intuition that we would have in this case. How do you explain this?

@Syed Let's suppose you see the run rise every day 1000 times. You could guess that the sun will rise tomorrow. That guess is either right or wrong and nothing about the number of times you have observed the sun rising tomorrow implies its correctness. The reason you have an intuition that the sun will rise tomorrow is that you have some previous cultural and biological knowledge so that you expect some kinds of regularity in the environment and look for them, i.e. - your ancestors capable of spotting those kinds of regularities were able to copy their genes better than their competitors.

@Syed Nothing about those expectations implies that those expectations are true or probable. The idea of justification can also lead to you ignoring problems with your ideas, e.g. the mere fact that the sun will rise tomorrow doesn't explain what time it will rise. In some places the sun may not always rise tomorrow, e.g. - the South pole. On a long enough timescale the sun may stop rising as a result of tidal locking between the Earth and the sun, the sun running out of hydrogen, the Earth possibly being ejected from the solar system etc.

sure, so are you saying that if someone feels more confident in the sun rising after seeing it rise for 1000 vs. 10 days, there is no philosophical basis to this, even if there is a psychological basis?

@Syed (1) Feelings of confidence have nothing to do with how you should judge some item of knowledge. People felt confident about lots of stuff that turned out to be wrong. (2) You should decide whether to adopt or act on ideas as a result of looking for and considering criticisms of those ideas. (3) Seeing the sun rising for 1000 days doesn't imply it will rise tomorrow except in the light of some explanation such as celestial mechanics and that theory is itself an unjustified guess. The best you can do is look for problems with your ideas and try to fix those problems.

@ScottRowe I don't know where you got that from what I wrote.

Induction is used to justify practically everything we do. Mathematicians and logicians like to use deductive proofs, but this is rarely the thinking process used in day-to-day life. We don't normally require absolute certainty for decision making. And even deductive proofs depend on premises that are must be simply accepted if we're trying to draw conclusions about the real world; these premises must have been determined inductively.
So to compare your two predictions, we might reason as follows:
Belief 1: The sun will rise tomorrow.
Confidence 1: Very high, practically certain.
Justification 1: The sun has risen every day for billions of years. Scientists are not aware of any reason why it won't continue to do so for the billions of years until it expands into a red dwarf.
Belief 2: I will be alive tomorrow.
Confidence 2: High, but possibly false.
Justification 2: I'm not currently suffering from any disease that's killing me, so I presume the status quo will be maintained. However, many people die unexpectedly every day: accidents happen, unpredicted medical issues arise, they can be the victim of a random shooting, etc. Since I'm not in any way special, there's no reason why one of those things couldn't happen to me tomorrow.
We often justify reasoning based on cause-and-effect. Here we can't imagine any causes that would prevent belief 1, but we can imagine causes that will prevent belief 2, so we're not as confident of it.

Exactly. Fuzzy logic. If we assign a probability at all for this kind of question, it is generally a vague spread of probabilities rather than any specific value. The additional value of trying to narrow that down is often not worth the time and effort that doing so would require.

Your argument is circular and has already been addressed by Hume. Saying that we can say that something is probably true rather than certainly true requires induction. You can’t justify induction with induction.

@Syed But you can assume induction dogmatically, and then use it to justify other things  (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%BCnchhausen_trilemma)

@Syed Or you can use induction as a rule of thumb/heuristically provisionally as long as it seems to work, and as soon as it ceases to work you just try to come up with something else.

@user80226 that just sounds like another way of saying there’s no justification for it

@Syed That's why science is about falsifying hypotheses rather than proving hypotheses. You can use induction as a rule of thumb to propose hypotheses (usually, laws) from observed regularities, but that doesn't mean that you are "justified". It's just a heuristic, and as long as it works (i.e., as long as you fail to falsify it), you stick with your unfalsified hypotheses. But as soon as the evidence contradicts them, you need to revise them. If the universe suddenly ceases to behave regularly invalidating induction, you will need to come up with new hypotheses.

You never have certainty, only hypotheses that you have failed to falsify as of yet.

@user80226 didn’t know you were a Popperian!

Of course it is possible. Take two cases, one being that the Sun will rise this morning, the other being that I am capable of lifting my car with one hand (no silly comments, please, along the lines of but what if you used a jack / tethered car to helium balloon / etc etc). How could I not have different degrees of confidence in those two statements? More generally, how do you imagine humans as a species would have survived if they did not form an ability to make judgments about whether one thing was more or less likely than another? Consider some practical judgements very possibly taken by a remote ancestor that led to you being alive today. Am I more likely to hurt myself jumping off a four foot high rock than a 1000 foot cliff? Is the sabre tooth tiger a bigger threat when a foot away than when a mile away? Am I safer following the longer path on firm ground than the direct route across the glutinous quaking bog in which I see a mastodon drowning? Etc etc etc. What is remarkable is how evolution has allowed us to redirect the mechanisms behind those rudimentary forms of reasoning so that today we can put them to use to post questions on Philosophy SE.

I mean I agree with you in principle but it seems that you have not really justified anything and have instead resorted to examples that seem obviously instinctual. I think the issue is highlighted more clearly when one asks: what does it mean to say that X is more likely than Y? I cannot think of a way that would decide this answer that wouldn’t ultimately just be a reflection of what I would personally bet on. For example, I, would always bet that death is more likely than not jumping off a cliff. It seems obvious. The question is how one would justify this non circularly

What makes you think the mind works that way? If you put your finger in a fire as a child, the belief you develop that you should not do so again is not arrived at through a process of logical reasoning.

I did not say that the mind works that way. I am saying that there seems to be no philosophical justification for things that we all deem to be obvious, such as the belief that we should not put our finger on the fire

Perhaps your mistake is looking for what you call a philosophical justification. Would you insist on a philosophical justification for other everyday phenomena, such as an egg breaking if dropped on a hard floor? I suppose not. So why expect a philosophical justification for that other everyday phenomenon known as thinking?

I put my finger in the fire. Various chemicals processes take place which have the effect of creating links between neurone in my head that have the effect of discouraging me from inserting my finger a second time. That's how you 'know' a fire is hot.

That's what it 'means' to say that you consider burning your hand if you put it in a fire to be more likely than not.

I am in agreement that we perhaps should not or do not require a philosophical justification for certain things. But then, if we can’t even arrive at a philosophical justification for things that seem obvious, what is the point of philosophy?

Your last question wins the prize. Most of philosophy is ultimately tautologous or arbitrary classification of concepts. Some of it can help clear one's thinking, however.

The point of philosophy as I understand it is to push ideas around according to rules which allow deductions to be made, conditional upon the premises,  and see if that sparks new ideas, preferably testable ones or ones which show that the premises are questionable. In that way, it is equivalent to mathematics; it provides a structured (and thus, hopefully, less error prone) way to explore the implications of what we already think we know and/or to see what some of the implications would be of a hypothetical.
